# line spacing with cdn

Tags: ckeditor, cdn

How do I set ckeditor with single line spacing if I am using the cdn?

I see several plug-ins to address this but I just want to use the cdn and have it single space when I hit the enter key.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ckeditor doesn't add extra line spacing, it just adds a p tag for every paragraph written, and when you press ENTER a new p paragraph tag is created for the next paragraph you write.

What you're seeing is probably the `margin-bottom: 25px;` CSS rule that's applied by default to paragraphs. To reduce this margin, just create a CSS file with a rule like this:

```
body.article-editor p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Even if you're just importing the CDN, I assume you're initializing ckeditor somewhere in your code inside a `<script>` tag. In this JavaScript code, set the CKEDITOR configuration contentsCss as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/css/mysitestyles.css';
```

For more information on how this works, check the documentation on the contentsCss configuration property:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss

---

*Edit after feedback:*

Thank you for sharing your code. I've corrected your HTML a bit as you had a couple minor HTML mistakes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.12.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = 'mystyles.css';
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, since you're using Ckeditor in text edit mode instead of article edit mode, please use this CSS instead:

```
.cke_editable p {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

This works in Firefox latest version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still having issues. A newbie here so please bear with me. I added the body.article-editor p...to mystyles.css, and added the config per your instructions. still not working. here is my tiny index.html.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.12.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
                
        </head>
        <body>
            
                <textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = 'mystyles.css';
                        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                        
                </script>
                
        </body>
</html>

Comment: mystyles.css is in the same directory as index.html

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome :) please remember to mark this as the answer